# Clipping a partly off screen textured quad via code gives performance gain?

Tags: android, ios, graphics, opengl-es

I'm writing a 2d mobile game that has huge textures for the backgrounds and i was wondering if and how the graphic hardware optimizes drawing of items that are partly / completely out of the screen.

I'm expecting it to at least skip rasterization of pizels that fall out of the buffer.

So i was wondering if i could expect a performance gain in drawing only the visible part of the texture to the screen using a smaller quad or the gain in performance would be trivial?

The situation could be summed up like this: 
1) few quads, 
2) big textures, 
3) many of the quads are partly on screen.

Comment: That is of course all implementation specific. But I really wouldn't exepect a performance gain here. The GPUs are quide efficient and clipping, and especially at _avoiding_ the clipping at all, like using guard band clipping. In the ideal case, the "clipping" will be completely free on the GPU. However, all of that only applies to objects which are at least partly visible. You could gain something by simple frustum culling, where you don't even try to draw the objects which are completely outside the frustum, though. But that again will depend on the situation.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i will move my optimization time elsewhere ;)